# Espresso: android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException for AdapterView

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-adapterview

I am trying to run an espresso test using `onData` and everything works fine for a view that has only one AdapterView inside of it.  However, when the screen shows a view that has multiple adapter views nested in it, I get:

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.

Is there any way to specify which adapter view `onData` should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of the answer, let's assume that one of your adapterviews is an ExpandableListView and the other is a ListView and that they can be easily identified by their unique id in the layout file.

All you need to do is use the `isDescendentOfA` matcher to isolate your desired AdapterView like so:

```
onData(...).
inAdapterView(allOf(
    isAssignableFrom(AdapterView.class),
    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.listView))))
```

However, if your adapter views don't have different ids, just look through their various attributes, and you may find uniquely identifiable properties against which you can narrow down your selection.